# java 8 lambda generics comparator - compiler warnings

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, comparator

This lambda expression to compare 2 objects:

```
private static final Comparator NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR1 = 
        (Comparator) (final Object o1, final Object o2) -> ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
```

produces this compile warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type Comparable
(Comparator) (final Object o1, final Object o2) -> ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

This lambda expression to compare 2 T objects:

```
private final Comparator<T> NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR2 = 
        (Comparator<T>) (final T o1, final T o2) -> ((Comparable<T>) o1).compareTo(o2);
```

produces this compile warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
(Comparator<T>) (final T o1, final T o2) -> ((Comparable<T>) o1).compareTo(o2);
required: Comparable<T>
found:    T
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class Tree01
```

Your resolution with explanation/comments much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can’t define a `Comparator` that can compare arbitrary `Comparable`s as you can’t compare a `String` to an `Integer`, despite both implementing `Comparable`. You need a type variable to formulate the constraint that both arguments of the `Comparator.compare` method have to be compatible for a comparison.

But it is impossible to define such a generic `Comparator` using a field, as you can’t introduce type parameters when declaring a field. It only works using a factory method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder() {
    return (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b);
}
```

or

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder() {
    return Comparable::compareTo;
}
```

which you can use like

```
Comparator<Integer> ci = naturalOrder();
Comparator<String> cs  = naturalOrder();
// in the current version of Oracle's JRE/OpenJDK this will print true
System.out.println(ci==(Object)cs);
```

which shows that with the given JRE, it produces a singleton instance, being on par with a comparator stored in a field in terms of performance. But from the Generics point of view, they have incompatible types, making it impossible to define a single variable holding that comparator and being compatible with `Integer` and `String` at the same time.

The impossibility to declare a field with type parameters is the reason why `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` got complemented with `Collections.emptyList()` when Generics were introduced or why the new method [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--), addressing the same purpose as your attempt, is a method rather than a field.

Comment: Thank you, Holger. That makes sense and nicely explained (a programmer for the president).